# $O(3)/SO(3) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

Progress:

$\phi: O(3) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2$

$\psi: O(3) \rightarrow O(3)/SO(3)$

$\theta: O(3)/SO(3) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2$

$\phi(O) = \text{det} (O)$ with $O \in O(3)$, that way

$\phi(O) \mapsto \{-1,1\} \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$, where 1 is the identity element.

Ker($\phi$) = $\{O \in SO(3) | \phi(O)=1\} = SO(3) $, since $\text{det}(O)=1$ for $O \in SO(3).$

By the multiplicative property of the determinant function, $\phi$ = homomorphism.

---

***What is the form of the canonical homomorphism ($\psi$) in this case?

I'm used to the coset language,

i.e. $\psi: G \rightarrow G/\text{Ker}(\phi)$ with $\psi(g)=gK$ for $K=\text{ker}(\phi)$

---

If this were settled, then $\theta$ is an isomorphism by the isomorphism theorem.

Comment: You have concluded that $\phi$ is a group homomorphism with kernel $SO(3)$, so you can conclude that $O(3)/SO(3) = O(3)/\text{ker}(\phi) \conj \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Is it not necessary to establish the concrete form of $\psi$?

Comment: I don't understand what you need $\psi$ for. If you are just asked to prove that $O(3)/SO(3) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$, then what I wrote is enough. If you need to write down the explicit isomorphism, well, that's just the determinant.

Comment: What is the question? What do you mean by the “form” of $\psi$?

Comment: Question is to show the isomorphism listed in the title. I'm just thinking in terms of the commuting diagram that illustrates the isomorphism theorem. It doesn't seem right to utilize the isomorphism theorem is i dont have a concrete formula for the canonical homomorphism as well.

Answer (score 2):

The mere fact that $O(3)/SO(3) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ does not imply that there even needs to be a map $\psi: O(3) \to SO(3)$; in general there aren't homomorphisms from non-abelian groups to their subgroups (or even normal subgroups). After all: how do we know where to send the elements in the big group that are not part of the small group?

That said: in this special case the map $\psi$ does exist. The point is that *not only* do we have $O(3)/SO(3) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ but we even have:

$$O(3) \cong SO(3) \times \mathbb{Z}_2$$

which means that indeed we do have four maps, your $\phi$ and $\psi$ pointing out of $O(3)$ onto its factors and in the other direction we have embeddings $SO(3) \to O(3)$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2 \to O(3)$.

The decomposition $O(3) \cong SO(3) \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ can be seen really concretely:

every determinant 1 matrix $A$ in $O(3)$ corresponds to the pair $(A, 1)$ in $SO(3) \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and for every $B \in O(3)$ with determinant minus one we have that $-B$ lives in $SO(3)$ and we let $B$ correspond with the pair $(-B, -1)$ in $SO(3) \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Now I leave it to you to get the projection operator $\psi$ out of this picture.

EDIT: when it comes to $\theta$: as the comments say you only need to understand $\phi$ to get that $\theta$ is an isomorphism by the isomorphism theorem; this part works also in cases where the big group is *not* a direct product of the smaller group and the quotient (and $\psi$ does not exist).

EDIT 2: I thought seeing an example where there is no map $\psi$ would help you clarify this issue. Here is one: take the dihedral group $D_4$ with eight elements, so the symmetry group of a square. This is the big group, similar to $O(3)$ in your example. Take $C_4$ the cyclic group of four elements as the small group. You can write down $\phi$ and $\theta$, the quotient is again the two element group. Also thinking about $D_4$ as symmetries of the square, there is a nice geometric analogy with your case: the small group consists of rotations only while the big group consists of rotations AND reflections. However in this case there is no homomorphism from the big group to the small one.

Comment: I apologize for the mistake, $\psi: O(3) \rightarrow O(3)/SO(3)$. But I am incredibly interested in your answer, as I follow-up question I was going to post after getting a handle on this (oh wait I already did, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3412222/is-proving-o3-cong-mathbbz-2-otimes-so3-equivalent-to-proving-o3-so) was regarding proving $O(3)\cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \otimes SO(3)$. I am having a hard time working through your answer though, let me get back to you.

Comment: Please do get back! In the mean time I wrote an answer on your other question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the codomain of $\psi$ is wrong, it should be $O(3)/SO(3)$ (which is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2$). Then the form is precisely as you described. More concretely,
$\varphi(O) = SO(3)$ if $\det O = 1$, and $\varphi(O) = O(3) \setminus SO(3)$ otherwise. Note that $O(3) \setminus SO(3)$ is actually equal to $(-I)\cdot SO(3)$.

Comment: thank you for the codomain point!